Dockerized php-fpm status on port 9000 integration with dockerized prometheus exporter for PHP-FPM
I've set up my php-fpm status in /status. I'm having problems collecting this information with php-fpm_exporter using a tcp connection.
My stack: Docker(aws ecs ec2) + Nginx+php-fpm
I'm using hipages/php-fpm-exporter
I need to know how to expose port 9000 so that the exporter can connect to php-fpm-status. Errors
www.conf
[pool]

listen = 0.0.0.0:9000
...
pm.status_path = /status

default.conf
server {
    listen       80 default_server;
    listen       [::]:80 default_server;
    server_name  _;
    root         /var/www/html;

    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
      return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    index index.php index.html index.htm default.html default.htm;
    location /_upload/s3/ {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /_upload/s3/get.php?$args;
    }

    error_page 500 /errors/500.php;
    error_page 404 /errors/404.php;
    error_page 403 /errors/perm.php;
    autoindex off;

    location ~ [^/]\.php(/|$) {
        if (!-f $document_root$fastcgi_script_name) {
            return 404;
        }
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;

        proxy_connect_timeout  600;
        proxy_send_timeout  600;
        proxy_read_timeout  600;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 600;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600;
    }

    location /v2 {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /v2/index.html;
    }

    location /status {
        fastcgi_pass   localhost:9000;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }
}

When I access <ip>/status I have access to the status.
return 1
When I access <ip>:9000/status I get a connection refused message
return 2
Notes:

The same logic applies to the browser and internal ip.
I need the connection to be made via IP, because the exporter runs on another server and connects to the docker application via IP.


Welcome to Stack Overflow! [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [sf] would be better places for questions like this.

You need to know how that exporter works? Or you need to know how to export port 9000 from the docker container? With the first question I'm with @Barmar, with the second you should find the information already on site.

Hi,
The exporter works by connecting to port 9000 of php-fpm. It reads the status page.
What happens is that I don't know if the configuration I made is correct, it seems that the fpm status page is only available on port 80. So the exporter can't read the information.

@juanferreira: Port 80 looks legit to me as you're using the webserver to connect to fpm.   Now similar to what you did with the webserver to connect to fpm, you have to do with the exporter.  According to your question, your webserver is using 127.0.0.1 and port 9000 (from fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;), and your problem is likely you don't run the exporter in the same container. Create a docker composition with docker compose, this is more declarative and you automatically have one network for the composition. Commit early and often. Then tell the exporter to connect to fpm port 9000.

I'm using ECS with EC2. Locally (my computer), I can access with the docker name, but ECS has some limitations regarding name resolution. Therefore, I need the IP to be accessible in order to connect to the exporter in another context.

Hey, 9000 port most probably not exposed externally and it shouldn't. If you deploy exporter outside of your app, then need configuration parameter "--phpfpm.scrape-uri" to be adjusted. Try to set it to your app IP address on 80 port and it should work.
Here is the details of all configuration parameters:
https://github.com/hipages/php-fpm_exporter?tab=readme-ov-file#options-and-defaults
